# AudioTrack - short array to byte array distortion using jlayer(java mp3 decoder)

Tags: java, android, mp3, pcm, jlayer

I'm using jLayer to decode MP3 data, with this call:

```
SampleBuffer output = (SampleBuffer) decoder.decodeFrame(frameHeader, bitstream);
```

This call which returns the decoded data, returns an array of short[].
   `output.getBuffer();`

When I call AudioTrack write() with that method, it plays fine as I loop through the file:

```
at.write(output.getBuffer(), 0, output.getBuffer().length);
```

However, when I convert the short[] array to byte[] array using any of the methods in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12347176/1176436 the sound gets distorted and jittery:

```
at.write(output.getBuffer(), 0, output.getBuffer().length);
```

becomes:

```
byte[] array = ShortToByte_Twiddle_Method(output.getBuffer());
at.write(array,  0,  array.length);
```

Am I doing anything wrong and what can I do to fix it? Unfortunately I need the pcm data to be in a byte array for another 3rd party library I'm using.  The file is 22kHz if that matters and this is how at is being instantiated:

```
at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 22050, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 10000 /* 10 second buffer */,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Edit: This is how I'm instantiating the AudioTrack variable now. So for 44kHz files, the value that is getting sent is 44100, while for 22kHz files, the value is 22050.

```
at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, decoder.getOutputFrequency(), 
                                  decoder.getOutputChannels() > 1 ? AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO : AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                                  AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 10000 /* 10 second buffer */,
                                  AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

This is decode method:

```
public byte[] decode(InputStream inputStream, int startMs, int maxMs) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);

        float totalMs = 0;
        boolean seeking = true;

        try {
            Bitstream bitstream = new Bitstream(inputStream);
            Decoder decoder = new Decoder();

            boolean done = false;
            while (!done) {
                Header frameHeader = bitstream.readFrame();
                if (frameHeader == null) {
                    done = true;
                } else {
                    totalMs += frameHeader.ms_per_frame();

                    if (totalMs >= startMs) {
                        seeking = false;
                    }

                    if (!seeking) {
                        // logger.debug("Handling header: " + frameHeader.layer_string());
                        SampleBuffer output = (SampleBuffer) decoder.decodeFrame(frameHeader, bitstream);                            

                        short[] pcm = output.getBuffer();
                        for (short s : pcm) {
                            outStream.write(s & 0xff);
                            outStream.write((s >> 8) & 0xff);
                        }
                    }

                    if (totalMs >= (startMs + maxMs)) {
                        done = true;
                    }
                }
                bitstream.closeFrame();
            }

            return outStream.toByteArray();
        } catch (BitstreamException e) {
            throw new IOException("Bitstream error: " + e);
        } catch (DecoderException e) {
            throw new IOException("Decoder error: " + e);
        }
    }
```

This is how it sounds (wait a few seconds): https://vimeo.com/60951237  (and this is the actual file: http://www.tonycuffe.com/mp3/tail%20toddle.mp3)

Edit:  I would have loved to have split the bounty, but instead I have given the bounty to Bill and the accepted answer to Neil. Both were a tremendous help. For those wondering, I ended up rewriting the Sonic native code which helped me move along the process.

Comment: It appears that the decoding works when the file is 44kHz sample rate, but for 22kHz, it becomes completely choppy.

Comment: Can you give an overview of the flow.  What is the purpose of the 3rd party library.  Is it a filter?  Ie, Bytes in/Bytes out?  Or you don't use the library and just decode a 22/44kHz mp3 and play it.  One after converting to 8bits and another at 16bits?

Comment: It's Sonic, a rate modification engine. Basically, it allows me to modify the playback rate (speed up, slow down) while maintaining pitch (not sounding chipmunky, etc).

Comment: So once I get a suitable amount of byte[]s back, I can send it to sonic and it spits back modified byte[]s, which I pass to AudioTrack. With 44kHz files it works beautifully (even with playback rate modification).  Even if I take out the sonic conversion for 22 khz files, it sounds pretty bad.

Comment: Yes :). I don't get anything near the sound that I'd be expecting, just a couple of "Thuds" (like someone hitting a microphone).

Comment: It is indeed the library. If you notice, it takes: sonic.putBytes(in,  in.length);. If it took a short[], I'd be done already :).

Comment: The standard NDK version is here, https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic-ndk/blob/master/src/org/vinuxproject/sonic/Sonic.java However, this library supports bytes, unsigned bytes, shorts and float? http://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic/blob/master/Sonic.java Also, you are free to use the Sonic.class unaltered in your own jar (or whatever the android thing is [apk?]).

Comment: I tried the Java version, but it keeps running into arrayOutOfBoundExceptions.

Comment: It works fine without compilation. The author states it's a pure Java implementation. The main sonic library is already compiled and that part is working fine.

Comment: See: Sonic.java
   // Use this to write 16-bit data to be speed up or down into the stream.
   // Return false if memory realloc failed, otherwise true.
    public boolean putBytes(byte[] buffer, int lenBytes), so the interface is **NOT** bytes, it is 16bit!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25482/discussion-between-bill-pringlemeir-and-stackoverflowed)

Comment: This question got closed, but 5 people voted it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Bill Pringlemeir says, the problem is that your conversion method doesn't actually convert. A short is a 16 bit number; a byte is an 8 bit number. The method you have chosen doesn't convert the contents of the shorts (ie go from 16 bits to 8 bits for the contents), it changes the way in which the same collection of bits is stored. As you say, you need something like this:

```
SampleBuffer output = (SampleBuffer) decoder.decodeFrame(frameHeader, bitstream);
byte[] array = MyShortToByte(output.getBuffer());
at.write(array,  0,  array.length);
```

@Bill Pringlemeir's approach is equivalent to dividing all the shorts by 256 to ensure they fit in the byte range:

```
byte[] MyShortToByte(short[] buffer) {
    int N = buffer.length;
    ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(N);
    while (N >= i) {
        byte b = (byte)(buffer[i]/256);  /*convert to byte. */
        byteBuf.put(b);
        i++;
    }
    return byteBuf.array();
}
```

This will work, but will probably give you very quiet, edgy tones. If you can afford the processing time, a two pass approach will probably give better results:

```
byte[] MyShortToByte(short[] buffer) {
    int N = buffer.length;
    short min = 0;
    short max = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
         if (buffer[i] > max) max = buffer[i];
         if (buffer[i] < min) min = buffer[i];
         }
    short scaling = 1+(max-min)/256; // 1+ ensures we stay within range and guarantee no divide by zero if sequence is pure silence ...

    ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(N);
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        byte b = (byte)(buffer[i]/scaling);  /*convert to byte. */
        byteBuf.put(b);
    }
    return byteBuf.array();
}
```

Again, beware signed / unsigned issue. The above works signed-> signed and unsigned->unsigned; but not between the two. It may be that you are reading signed shorts (-32768-32767), but need to output unsigned bytes (0-255), ...

If you can afford the processing time, a more precise (smoother) approach would be to go via floats (this also gets round the signed/unsigned issue):

```
byte[] MyShortToByte(short[] buffer) {
    int N = buffer.length;
    float f[] = new float[N];
    float min = 0.0f;
    float max = 0.0f;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
         f[i] = (float)(buffer[i]);
         if (f[i] > max) max = f[i];
         if (f[i] < min) min = f[i];
         }
    float scaling = 1.0f+(max-min)/256.0f; // +1 ensures we stay within range and guarantee no divide by zero if sequence is pure silence ...

    ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(N);
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        byte b = (byte)(f[i]/scaling);  /*convert to byte. */
        byteBuf.put(b);
    }
    return byteBuf.array();
}
```

Comment: I tried your conversion, it still sounds choppy. Maybe I should be padding the byte array with 0s at each conversion?

Comment: A little bit, still choppy however.

Comment: If you can bear the processing cost, or at least if you can fro an experiment, try the alternative I'll put above in the next couple of minutes. If it's still choppy, then it is very unlikely that this conversion is the cause, and more likely that something else is the issue

Comment: The float alternative is now up to try, but I can't edit the previous comment to reflect this ...

Comment: I tried both, still choppy.  You can see the editted question at the end for the intended sound as well as the outputted sound.

Comment: +1 for suggesting re-normalizing.  I think that the mp3 decoder may produce 16bit values that are swapped versus processor endian-ness.

Comment: I've just read your edits. You are setting the encoding to 16bits when you set up the AudioTrack, yet we are converting the data to 8 bit here. Did you change that to AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT as @BillPringlemeir says? I'm also a bit confused as the decoder you've posted appears to return a byte array yet earlier you say it returns a short array. Or have I missed something?

Comment: @Neil: I think there is more than one thing going on.  Take a look at `putBytesNative` at https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic-ndk/tree/master/jni  If you follow it through, it seem even though the top-level Java interface is `putBytes()`, it is actually treating the `byte` buffer as `shorts`.  Also, it is not clear what the endian-ness of the mp3 decoder is.  As soon as we try to **munge** the PCM, we have issue (except at 44k? Why?).  The endian-ness/PCM size of the `AudioTrack/AudioFormat` also must be correct to get good sound.

Comment: I could well believe we have an endian issue here. Do you think an endian swap in the short would be a good idea, ie changing f[i] = (float)(buffer[i]); to f[i] = (float)((256*(buffer[i]%256) + buffer[i]/256)); would be worth trying out?

Comment: I must say I really appreciate how much you guys are trying to help out. Hopefully once this is settled I'll be able to compensate you guys better than in a way of bounty.  Sonic is not a problem with regards to the distortion because even without sonic in the equation, once I convert from short[] to byte[], 22 kHz files no longer sound as originally encoded.  The original code was from this article, and one person in the comments had the same problem: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/624/android-audio-play-an-mp3-file-on-an-audiotrack/

Comment: The other person's problem "Great blog, I was just wondering about the check from lines 29-32. I do have a case where my generated mp3 is 22khz mono. I tried removing the check and running the conversion ￼ on audio track I get an alien sound. If I run the code as a desktop application and save the result in a wav file no editor can identify it. Thanks in advance ￼"

Comment: The code in that article specifically claims to only work for 44k, so I guess that at 22k there is something different about the data returned. I'm afraid I'm out of ideas for the night, but would be interested to know if the endian switch suggested above works ...

Comment: Thanks for trying, seriously. Like I said, the 22k file is being returned perfectly as a short[], but getting muddled when being converted to byte[]. So the decoding is actually going well, it's when I start to play with the audio data that things getting screwy.

Comment: Other idea: When you went from 44 to 22 kHz, did anything else change? Did it go from stereo to mono or mono to stereo?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>The issue is with your `short` to `byte` conversion.  The [byte conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12347176/1176436) link preserves all information including the high and low `byte` portions.  When you are converting from 16bit to 8bit [PCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) samples, you must discard the lower byte.  My Java skills are weak, so the following may not work verbatim.  See also: [short to byte conversion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114935/convert-from-short-to-byte-and-viceversa-in-java)</strike>

```
ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(N);
while (N >= i) {
  /* byte b = (byte)((buffer[i]>>8)&0xff);  convert to byte. native endian */
 byte b = (byte)(buffer[i]&0xff);  /*convert to byte; swapped endian. */
 byteBuf.put(b);
  i++;
}
```

That is the following conversion,

```
  AAAA AAAA SBBB BBBB  -> AAAA AAAA, +1 if S==1 and positive else -1 if S==1
```

`A` is a bit that is kept.  `B` is a discarded bit and `S` is a bit that you may wish to use for rounding.  The rounding is not needed, but it may sound a little better.  Basically, 16 bit PCM is higher resolution than 8 bit PCM.  You *lose* those bits when the conversion is done.  The `short` to `byte` routine tries to preserve all information.

Of course, you must tell the sound library that you are using `8-bit PCM`.  My guess,

```
at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 22050, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, 10000 /* 10 second buffer */,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

If you can only use `16bit PCM` to play audio, then you have to do the inverse and convert the `8bit PCM` from the library to `16bit PCM` for playback.  Also note, that typically, `8bit` samples are often **NOT** straight PCM but [u-law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-law_algorithm) or [a-law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-law_algorithm) encoded.  If the 3<sup>rd</sup> party library uses these formats, the conversion is different but you should be able to code it from the wikipedia links.

**NOTE:** I have not included the rounding code as `overflow` and `sign` handling will complicate the answer.  You must check for `overflow` (Ie, 0x8f + 1 gives 0xff or 255 + 1 giving -1).  However, I suspect the library is not straight `8bit PCM`.

See Also: [Alsa PCM overview](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm.html), [Multi-media wiki entry on PCM](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=PCM) - Ultimately Android uses **ALSA** for sound.

Other factors that must be correct for a PCM raw buffer are sample rate, number of channels (stereo/mono), PCM format including bits, *companding*, little/big endian and sample interleaving.

**EDIT:** After some investigation, the JLayer decoder typically returns `big endian` 16bit values.  The **Sonic filter**, takes a `byte` but threats them as 16bit `little endian` underneath.  Finally, the `AudioTrack` class expects 16 bit `little endian` underneath.  I believe that for some reason the `JLayer` mp3 decoder will return 16bit `little endian` values.  The `decode()` method in the question does a byte swap of the 16 bit values.  Also, the posted audio sounds as if the bytes are swapped.

```
public byte[] decode(InputStream inputStream, int startMs, int maxMs, bool swap) throws IOException {
...
                    short[] pcm = output.getBuffer();
                    for (short s : pcm) {
                        if(swap) {
                          outStream.write(s & 0xff);
                          outStream.write((s >> 8) & 0xff);
                        } else {
                          outStream.write((s >> 8) & 0xff);
                          outStream.write(s & 0xff);
                        }
                    }
...
```

For 44k mp3s, you call the routine with `swap = true;`.  For the 22k mp3 `swap = false`.  This explains all the reported phenomena.  I don't know why the `JLayer` mp3 decoder would sometimes output `big endian` and other times `little endian`.  I imagine it depends on the source mp3 and not the sample rate.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, I'm in the process of trying it. I think I understand what you're saying, but why would a 44kHz file converted in the original method and set as 16 bit pcm work?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, when I switch to the 22 kHz file, I switch the AudioTrack instantiation to be at 22050. In fact, it's now handled automatically.  Please see the edit to see the new instantiation.

Comment: 0 [Tuna           ]: OMAP4 - Tuna
                      TI OMAP4 Board
 1 [OMAP4HDMI      ]: OMAP4HDMI - OMAP4HDMI
                      OMAP4HDMI

Comment: How would that be possible? The problem is, the act of converting the short[] to byte[] is causing the audio corruption, which happens before Sonic gets the data. If I send to the audiotrack the array as shorts, it sounds perfectly fine. If I send it as a byte[] array, for 44 kHz files it works just as well, for 22 kHz, well:  https://vimeo.com/60951237

Comment: Ok. I didn't know that 22k works with 16bit. It still seems like the problem is the conversion OR specifying the PCM playback. It is NOT the driver. The 16bit sample maybe *big-endian* or *little-endian*. Please look at my edit and try that **without** Sonic.  It appears the buffers take a *byte*, but the are converted to *short* by the sonic JNI methods.