# Regulate Android AudioTrack playback speed

Tags: android, streaming, audiotrack

I'm currently trying to playback audio using AudioTrack. Audio is received over the network and application continuously read data and add to an internal buffer. A separate thread is consuming data and using AudioTrack to playback.

Problems:

1. Audio playback fluctuate (feels like audio drop at a regular interval) continuously making it unclear.
2. Playback speed is too high or too low making them unrealistic.

In order to avoid the network latency and other factors I made the application to wait till it read enough data and playback at the end.

This makes the audio to play really fast. Here is a basic sample of logic I use.

```
    sampleRate = AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sampleRate,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT),
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
audioTrack.play();

short shortBuffer[] = new short[AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)];
while (!stopRequested){
    readData(shortBuffer);
    audioTrack.write(shortBuffer, 0, shortBuffer.length, AudioTrack.WRITE_BLOCKING);
}
```

Is it correct to say that Android AudiTrack class doesn't have in built functionality to control the audio playback based on environment conditions? If so, are there better libraries available with a simplified way for audio playback?

Comment: Sample rate is retrieved from AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate() method (question updated). I have tried setting sample rate to different values but none of that worked.

Comment: And you're doing no DSP at all to the signal before you write it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The first** issue that I see, it is an arbitrary sampling rate.

`AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate` will return the sampling rate that used by the sound system. It may be 44100, 48000, 96000, 192000 or whatever. But looks like you have audio data from some independent source, which produces the data on the very exact sampling rate.

Let's say audio data from the source is sampled at 44100 samples per second. If you start playing it at 96000 it will be speeded up and higher pitched.

So, use the sampling rate setting, along with the number of channels, sample format etc, as it given by the source, not relying on system defaults.

**The second**: are you sure the `readData` procedure always will be fast enough to successfully fill the buffer, whatever small the buffer is, and return back faster than the buffer is played?

You have created [AudioTrack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#AudioTrack(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) with [AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#getMinBufferSize(int,%20int,%20int)) passed as `bufferSizeInBytes` parameter.

The `getMinBufferSize` function returns a minimum possible size of the buffer that can be used at this parameter. Let's say it returned the size corresponding to a buffer of 10ms length. 
That means the new data should be prepared within this time interval. I.e. The time interval between previous `write` returned control and new `write` is performed should be less than the time size of the buffer.

So, if the `readData` function may delay for some reason longer than that time interval, the playback will be paused for that time, you'll hear small gaps in the playback.

The reasons why `readData` may delay could be various: if it's reading data from the file, then it may delay waiting for IO operations; if it allocates java objects, it may be bumped into garbage collector's delay; if it uses some kind of decoder of another kind of audio source which uses it's own buffering, it may periodically delay refilling the buffer.

But anyway, if you're not creating some kind of real-time synthesizer which should react as soon as possible to the user input, always use the buffer size reasonably high, but not less than `getMinBufferSize` returned. I.e.:

```
sampleRate = 44100;// sampling rate of the source

int bufSize = sampleRate * 4; // 1 second length; 4 - is the frame size: 2 chanels * 2 bytes per each sample
bufSize = max(bufSize, AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)); // Not less than getMinBufferSize returns
audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sampleRate,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                bufSize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot AterLux. Yes, you are correct, data is sent by a streaming device over RTP with steady sampling rate. However I don't have the details of its configuration. Secondly, the readData returns data from a data buffer and data is added to the buffer as and when it arrives to the mobile app. Only at the small time window which  read and write a lock is obtained. Apart from that both reading and wring from/to buffer happens in parallel threads.

Comment: Looking at the encoder settings of streaming device I can see it is using sampling rate of 16000.  What is the method to calculate required buffer size for data sampled at 16000?  If not enough data to fill the full length of the buffer should I fill the remaining length with silence (zero) ?

Comment: No, you should fill as much data as you have, but in the third parameter of "write" instead of `shortBuffer.length` you have to specify exact amount of data returned by `readData`. So if `readData` fills only part of the buffer, then it should return the number of actual data filled somehow.

Comment: readData use shortBuffer length as minimum length. If not enough data it returns zero indicate no data. If zero length is returned I push an empty array to with minimum size length to the AudioTrack.write.

Comment: Then, you should revise how `readData` fills the array. And definitely not to pass empty arrays to `write` method.

Comment: Empty array is an array of minimum buffer size filled with zero to represent silence. I'm assuming that's not good?

Comment: For 16000 sample rate with 2 channels what should be the frame size?

Comment: If data then nothing has to be written. Writing empty array will add a silence gap into the sound. Instead, consider making the sound buffer bigger and if there is no data just delay (e.g. by calling wait()) while waiting for the new data. Frame size is a number of channels multiplied by one sample size in bytes. I.e. for 2 channels it will be: for 16bit sample  - 4, for 8 bit - 2, for float - 8 etc. Size of data passed to `write` should be integer amount of frames

Comment: I'm already doing what you've suggested. However if I write data continuously without a delay in between audio playback really fast. If I add a delay it becomes better though it make the playback to stutter.

Comment: I hadn't use the correct frame size as you advised which was what causing the audio to fluctuate. After fixing that now audio playback speed is consistent. Only remaining problem is audio is doesn't sound natural. It appears to be caused by the playback speed is being little bit slower adding noise.

Comment: Again: it would be much easy if you gave an example of the recorded sound. Check sample size (is it really 16 bit? not 8?) check number of channels (is it stereo? Not mono?) Check sample align. You said you have a conversion from 8 bit to 16 bit. Make sure it is sample-aligned. I.e. half of one sample does not go into another.

Comment: would 16bit  (2 bytes) sample size with two channels mean only 1 byte per sample for each side?

Comment: 16bit is the sample size. For each channel they are the same, i.e 2 bytes per each channel, Total 4 bytes per frame (i.e. all channels together)

Answer (score 0):

Like user @pskink said,

> Most likely your sampleRate (or any other parameter passed to the
>   AudioTrack constructor) is invalid.

So I would start by checking what value you are actually setting the sample rate.

For reference, you can also set the speed of `AudioTrack` by calling the `setPlayBackParams` method:

```
public void setPlaybackParams (PlaybackParams params)
```

If you check the [AudioTrack docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack), you can see the [PlaybackParams docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/PlaybackParams) and can set the [speed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/PlaybackParams#setSpeed(float)) and [pitch](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/PlaybackParams#setPitch(float)) of the output audio. This object can then be passed to set the playback parameters within your AudioTrack object.

However, it is unlikely that you will need to use this if your only issue is the original constructor `sampleRate` (since we cannot see where the variable `sampleRate` comes from).

Comment: Sample rate is retrieved from AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate() method (added to the original question). I have tried setting sample rate to different values but none of that worked.