# short to byte and byte to short conversion in Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing a software in Android.  In a particular portion of software, I need to convert short to byte and re-convert to it to short. I tried below code but values are not same after conversion.

```
  short n, n1;
  byte b1, b2;
  n = 1200;
  // short to bytes conversion
  b1 = (byte)(n & 0x00ff);
  b2 = (byte)((n >> 8) & 0x00ff);

  // bytes to short conversion
  short n1 = (short)((short)(b1) | (short)(b2 << 8));
```

after executing the code values of n and n1 are not same. Why?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188660/convert-short-to-byte-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not get Grahams solution to work. This, however do work:

```
n1 = (short)((b1 & 0xFF) | b2<<8);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ByteBuffer:

```
final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
buf.put(shortValue);
buf.position(0);

// Read back bytes
final byte b1 = buf.get();
final byte b2 = buf.get();

// Put them back...
buf.position(0);
buf.put(b1);
buf.put(b2);

// ... Read back a short
buf.position(0);
final short newShort = buf.getShort();
```

edit: fixed API usage. Gah.

Comment: That's an absolute overkill, the OP's question can be solved by simply using bitwise operators, as shown in @Jave's answer

Comment: Except this solution doesn't care about endianness!

Comment: It's not a bad solution per se. If one wanted to save a large number of values or convert an array of shorts to bytes and then back, this is definitely worth considering. The simplest case - converting between one short/two bytes, as asked for, is preferably done without allocating a buffer.