# How to convert short array to byte array?

Tags: java, audio

I am working with audio, I saved audio data on short array. I want to convert it to a byte array to store the wav file. I don't know convert short[] to byte[]. Can you help me. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804852/how-to-convert-short-array-to-byte-array

Comment: thank you very much. I will try this code:

private byte[] shortArrayToByteArray(short[] shortArr) {
  int index;
  int iterations = shortArr.length;
  ByteBuffer  bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(shortArr.length * 2);
 
  for(index = 0; index != iterations; ++index){
    bb.putShort(shortArr[index]);    
  }
 
  return bb.array();       
 }

Comment: If you use ByteBuffer, make sure the byte order is correct for your system. The default is big endian, but many formats use little endian.

Comment: oh, thank you very much, I want to create little-endian.

Answer (score 2):

short is `16 bit` type and byte is `8 bit` type . So from a `n` length short array you will get a `2n` length byte array.

**The Basics**

before converting an array thing about converting a single short to byte. so as per above line you will create 2 byte from a single short.

The principle will be store first 8 bits two a byte and store second 8 bits to another short. The code will be like this

```
byte b1, b2;
short s;

b1 = s & 0xff;
b2 = (s >> 8) & 0xff;
```

**Now Array**

use the above principal for array now. say the array size of short is n. let the short is s

```
byte result[2*n];
for(int i = 0; i<2*n ; i=i+2){
    b[i]   = s[i>>1] & 0xff;
    b[i+1] = (s[i>>1 | 1] >> 8) & 0xff;
}
```

**Using ByteBuffer class**

you can also convert short array to bytearray using ByteBuffer class.

```
ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(2*n);
for(int i = 0; i<n ; i++) {
    byteBuf.putShort(buffer[i]);
}
```

Comment: You forgot about the endianness

Comment: And signedness. This will screw up your data badly, you should at least have used `>>>`

Comment: @icepack I used little endian for example.. the main goal of the question is not to make a byte array for him.. but to give him a concept.. Am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to create a byte array of the same size as the short array and copy the short array elements

Comment: thank you very much, I'm testing some code..