# Converting short array to byte array in JAVA

Tags: java, byte, arrays, short

I am confused on how to convert `short` array to `byte` array.
E.g. I have the follwoing `short` array

```
short[] shrt_array = new short[]{ 0x4 , 0xd7 , 0x86, 0x8c, 0xb2, 0x14, 0xc, 0x8b, 0x2d, 0x39, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x27, 0xcb, 0x2e, 0x79, 0x46, 0x36, 0x9d , 0x62, 0x2c };
```

By using this link [Converting short array to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804852/how-to-convert-short-array-to-byte-array) the two methods of conversion, I get the following two different `byte` arrays:

```
 expectedByteArray = new byte[] {
    (byte) 0x4, (byte) 0xd7, (byte) 0x86, 
    (byte) 0x8c, (byte) 0xb2, (byte) 0x14,  
    (byte) 0xc, (byte) 0x8b, (byte) 0x2d,
    (byte) 0x39, (byte) 0x2d, (byte) 0x2d, 
    (byte) 0x27, (byte) 0xcb, (byte) 0x2e, 
    (byte) 0x79, (byte) 0x46, (byte) 0x36,
    (byte) 0x9d, (byte) 0x62, (byte) 0x2c,  
    (byte) 0x0,  (byte) 0x0,  (byte) 0x0, 
    (byte) 0x0,  (byte) 0x0,  (byte) 0x0,  
    (byte) 0x0,  (byte) 0x0,  (byte) 0x0,  
    (byte) 0x0,  (byte) 0x0,  (byte) 0x0,  
    (byte) 0x0,  (byte) 0x0,  (byte) 0x0,  
    (byte) 0x0,  (byte) 0x0,  (byte) 0x0,  
    (byte) 0x0,  (byte) 0x0,  (byte)0x0};
```

Second result: `

```
expectedByteArray = new byte[] {
(byte) 0x4,  (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0xd7,  
(byte) 0x0,  (byte) 0x86,  (byte) 0x0,
(byte) 0x8c,  (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0xb2, 
(byte) 0x0,  (byte) 0x14,  (byte) 0x0, 
(byte) 0xc,  (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x8b, 
 (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x2d,  (byte) 0x0,
 (byte) 0x39,  (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x2d, 
 (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x2d,  (byte) 0x0, 
(byte) 0x27,  (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0xcb, 
 (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x2e,  (byte) 0x0, 
(byte) 0x79,  (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x46, 
 (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x36,  (byte) 0x0,
(byte) 0x9d,  (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x62,  
(byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x2c,  (byte) 0x0};
```

`

Can you help me which is the right one.

Comment: What do you mean by "right"? It depends on your requirements. Do you need to convert each `short` into a single `byte` (e.g. by ignoring the top 8 bits) or into two `byte` values?

Comment: I have to convert each short into byte. Every value of short array into byte array

Comment: What john is pointing out is that a short is two bytes.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625573/byte-array-to-short-array-and-back-again-in-java?rq=1

Comment: A Short is 2 bytes wide, so your answer does not give the information, Jon asked for. You can convert either ignoring the top byte of the short, or by adding both bytes to the byte array. Which one do you need?

Comment: It is for me clear that a short is two bytes. Link that I posted they allocate a byte array 2*short_array.length. Which gives also a double size in compare to short_array. But what I do not udesrtand is, whcih shuld I consider as a corret byte array.

Comment: @Fildor, i need the second method, adding both bytes to the byte array.

Comment: just a side note, variable names should be in camelCase. `shrt_array` should be shrtArray.

Comment: @student - In what order? Most significant byte first, or least significant byte first?

Comment: @Ingo, was it possible two explain or provide some code for both orders. This means MSB first and LSb first?

Comment: @student On your request, wrote an answer.

Answer (score 10):

Your use of `asShortBuffer` was somewhat close.  It should be:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(shrt_array.length * 2);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
buffer.asShortBuffer().put(shrt_array);
byte[] bytes = buffer.array();
```

Answer (score 5):

Doing it manually for explicit control of byte order:

```
byte[] tobytes(short[] shorts, boolean bigendian) {
    int n = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[2*shorts.length];

    for (n=0; n < shorts.length; n++) {
        byte lsb = shorts[n] & 0xff;
        byte msb = (shorts[n] >> 8) & 0xff;
        if (bigendian) {
            bytes[2*n]   = msb;
            bytes[2*n+1] = lsb;
        } else {
            bytes[2*n]   = lsb;
            bytes[2*n+1] = msb;
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

If `s` is the short value, you have least significant byte with `s & 0xff` and most significant byte as `(s >> 8) & 0xff`. You can put them at byte array index `2*n` and `2*n+1` in the order you want, where `n` is the index in the short array.