# ByteBuffer from short to byte[]

Tags: android, libgdx, byte

I let the user record a short snippet of sound. It´s stored as short[]

```
final int samples = 44100;
boolean isMono = true;
final short[] data = new short[samples * 5];
final AudioRecorder recorder = Gdx.audio.newAudioRecorder(samples, isMono);
final AudioDevice player = Gdx.audio.newAudioDevice(samples, isMono);
ByteBuffer buffer;
```

start to record:

```
public void startRecord(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                System.out.println("Record start:");
                recorder.read(data, 0, data.length);
                recorder.dispose();
                //buffer.putShort(data[1]);
                System.out.println("Record ended:");
            }

    }).start();
}
```

And play the recorded sound:

```
public void playRecorded(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            player.writeSamples(data, 0, data.length);
            player.dispose();

        }
    }).start();
}
```

I now need to store their audio snippet in filehandle. And to do so I need to convert it to byte[] from what I know.

Comment: Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10804934/2777098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
buffer.putShort(short_value);
return buffer.array();
```

Comment: Thanks! But since I handle the recorder in a void I can´t return buffer.array() ?

Comment: this is just an example of the method, use it like you need