# how to get endianess in Java or python?

Tags: java, python, c, endianness

In `C` I could the `Endianess` of the machine by the following method. how would I get using a `python` or `Java` program?. In Java, char is `2-bytes` unlike `C` where it is `1-byte`. I think it might not be possible with `python` since it is a `dynamic language`, but I could be wrong

```
bool isLittleEndian()
     {
       // 16 bit value, represented as 0x0100 on Intel, and 0x0001 else
       short pattern = 0x0001;
       // access first byte, will be 1 on Intel, and 0 else
       return *(char*) &pattern == 0x01;
     }
```

Comment: In theory you shouldn't need to know nor care about that. Why do you want to know the endianness?

Comment: Regardless of platform, Java is always big-endian.

Comment: @rgettman ofcourse, I know the information. but is it possible to code-up. it is an interview question

Comment: check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188660/convert-short-to-byte-in-java

Answer (score 7):

In Java, it's just

```
ByteOrder.nativeOrder();
```

...which returns either `BIG_ENDIAN` or `LITTLE_ENDIAN`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteOrder.html

Comment: But you only need to know this if you are dealing in "odd" interfaces (such as nio) that operate on machine-level data buffers, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The `(byte)` cast of `short` is defined in both Java and C to return the "little" end of the `short`, regardless of the endianness of the processor. And `>>` is defined to shift from "big" end to "little" end (and `<<` the opposite), regardless of the endianness of the processor.  Likewise `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, et al, are all defined to be independent of processor endianness.

So no sequence of operations in Java or C will detect endianness.  What is required is some sort of "alias" of one size value on top of another (such as taking the address of an `int` and casting to `char*`), but Java does not have any way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please have a look at this: http://www.bits.stephan-brumme.com/endianess.html; I am more familiar with Java than C. thats why I was interested to get endianess in Java using bitwise operations than using ByteOrder.native.Order()

Comment: @user1988876 - The routine at the top of that page is C code, and it uses aliasing of `short` and `char` to do its dirty work.  As I said, there's no way to do such aliasing in Java.

Comment: Thx for pointing out the error in my post... deleting it since I hate bad info, and was clearly incorrect in my post.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [sys.byteorder](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.byteorder):

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.byteorder
'little'
```

Or you can get endianness by yourself with a little help of the built-in [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) module:

```
import struct

def is_little():
    packed = struct.pack("i", 1)
    return packed[0] == "\x01";

print is_little()
```

That was all Python of course.

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

public class Endian {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        ByteOrder b = ByteOrder.nativeOrder();
        if (b.equals(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)) {
            System.out.println("Big-endian");
        } else {
        System.out.println("Little-endian");
        }
    }
}
```

valter