# Why method for ByteBuffer putShort(value) does not working correctly in my case?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bytebuffer, short

My task is convert short[] array to byte[] array, because need send bytes via socket. This is bytes for AudioTrack (Android)
For converting use this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188660/convert-short-to-byte-in-java/47905328?noredirect=1#comment82777398_47905328), specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2188693/6352712) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6472927/6352712)
This method gives only white noise, when try to convert short to byte array:

```
 val sampleBuffer = decoder.decodeFrame(frameHeader, bitstream) as SampleBuffer
 val pcm = sampleBuffer.buffer //pcm is short[] array 

byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(pcm.size * 2) // because 1 short = 2 bytes

while (pcm.size > i) {
   byteBuf.putShort(pcm[i]) 
   i++ 
}

auddioTrack.write(byteBuf.array(), 0, byteBuf.limit());
```

But this convert works fine:

```
var i = 0
    val byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(pcm.size * 2)
    val buff =  ByteBuffer.allocate(2)

    //pcm size equals 2304
    while (pcm.size > i) {
       // byteBuf.putShort(pcm[i])
      byteBuf.put(byteArrayOf((pcm[i].toInt() and 0x00FF).toByte(), ((pcm[i].toInt() and 0xFF00) shr (8)).toByte()))                       
     i++
    }

auddioTrack.write(byteBuf.array(), 0, byteBuf.limit());
```

Why has it happened?

Answer (score 1):

`byteBuf.array().size` will return the size of the buffer (`pcm.size * 2`) regardless of whether that many bytes were written into the buffer. You probably want `byteBuf.limit()` instead.

Comment: @Sergey What is the value of `pcm.size * 2`? What is the value of `byteBuf.limit()`? What is the type of `pcm[i]`?

Comment: type is short[] -- array , so when convert array short to array byte,  size of byte[] will be size*2

Comment: @Sergey Take a single `short`. Run it through `putShort()` versus `put(byte[])`. Tell us the input value, and the output value you get in each `array()`.

Comment: wiil do it later, now there is no time. need to work, sorry))

Answer (score 1):

You should set byte order to little endian in this case.

```
val buff =  ByteBuffer.allocate(2).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
```